# Group json nested object in php

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a json response like below:

```
$response ='[
    {
        "userSummaries": [
            {
                "id": "9910",
                "status": "Active",
                "name": "Jhon"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userSummaries": [
            {
                "id": "8754",
                "status": "Active",
                "name": "Jane"
            }
        ]
    }
]';
```

and I would like to group this by `userSummaries` with this php code:

```
$myArr = json_decode($response, true);  

    $result_arr = [];
    
    array_walk($myArr,function($v,$k) use (&$result_arr){
       $result_arr[key($v)] = $v[key($v)]; 
    });
    
   
echo json_encode($result_arr);
```

and the response only return one data:

```
{"userSummaries":[{"id":"8754","status":"Active","name":"Jane"}]}
```

Is it possible to get the output response like this?:

```
{"userSummaries":[{"id":"9910","status":"Active","name":"Jhon"}, {"id":"8754","status":"Active","name":"Jane"}, ]}
```

Tried over the net but I did not found the solutions

here my script for this: https://3v4l.org/tVkK5

also tried this:

```
$class_array = array();
foreach ($myArr as $sa) {
    $class_array[$sa['userSummaries']][] = array('name' => $sa['name']);
}
```

but return:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in /in/hvSFC on line 28

Warning: Illegal offset type in /in/hvSFC on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: name in /in/hvSFC on line 28

Warning: Illegal offset type in /in/hvSFC on line 28
[]
```

need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You just needed to reference the key and first of `userSummaries` in each loop, instead of working with the whole...

```
$myArr = json_decode($response, true);
$result_arr = ["userSummaries"=>[]];
foreach($myArr as $user) {
    $result_arr["userSummaries"][] = $user['userSummaries'][0];
}
echo json_encode($result_arr);
```

Results in:

```
{"userSummaries":[
    {"id":"9910","status":"Active","name":"Jhon"},
    {"id":"8754","status":"Active","name":"Jane"}
]}
```

---

If you foresee that userSummaries in each will have multiple users themselves... then this would work:

```
$response ='[
    {
        "userSummaries": [
            {
                "id": "9910",
                "status": "Active",
                "name": "Jhon"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userSummaries": [
            {
                "id": "8754",
                "status": "Active",
                "name": "Jane"
            },
            {
                "id": "5421",
                "status": "Active",
                "name": "Bob"
            }
        ]
    }
]';

$myArr = json_decode($response, true);
$result_arr = ["userSummaries"=>[]];
foreach($myArr as $usergroup) {
    foreach($usergroup['userSummaries'] as $user) {
        $result_arr["userSummaries"][] = $user;
    }
}
echo json_encode($result_arr);
```

Results in:

```
{"userSummaries":[
    {"id":"9910","status":"Active","name":"Jhon"},
    {"id":"8754","status":"Active","name":"Jane"},
    {"id":"5421","status":"Active","name":"Bob"}
]}
```